# How can I insert an associative array into PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

I need to make the following arrangement in PHP with SQL result:

- Luis
- Carlos
- Pedro

```
if (!$result) {
  echo "An error occurred.\n";
  exit;
}

while($array = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
  $list = $array['list'];
}

pg_free_result($result);
```

But only `pedro` returns in the array.

Comment: You're defining `$list =` in every iteration of your `while` loop, the `$list` will only be the last row. Look into how to push values to an array, or concatenate strings, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You need pg_fetch_assoc() to get an associative array returned.

And you need to establish an array where you append nodes:

```
$lists = [];
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $lists[] = $row['list'];
}
```

Or use pg_fetch_all_columns() if you are just going to play with one.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-all-columns.php

```
$lists = pg_fetch_all_columns($result, 0);
```

0 means the first column in the rows.

Comment: Please close duplicates instead of answering them.

Comment: I didn't have the impression it was an accurate duplicate question linked.